# Opening and closing PHP tags several times in one document

Tags: php

Is there a performance issue when you open and close multiple PHP tags?

For instance this:

```
<tr><td><?= $value ?></td></tr>
<tr><td><?= $value ?></td></tr>
<tr><td><?= $value ?></td></tr>
<tr><td><?= $value ?></td></tr>
```

versus:

```
<?php
echo "<tr><td>{$value}</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>{$value}</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>{$value}</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>{$value}</td></tr>";
?>
```

Thinking about this over a very large test case.

Comment: The second one could be written as one big echo statement by concatenating the strings, but I have no idea if PHP itself does optimisations like that.